# How to change Helo Address?

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix, smtp, mail-server

Right now my Helo Address = localhost (helo=localhost). Is it better to set this to my server's domain name? If so, how do I change it? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and Postfix. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change it in postfix configuration file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

The helo line is controlled by the [`smtpd_banner`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_banner) parameter. It probably references the `myhostname` option. Put your server name there instead of `localhost`:

```
myhostname = server.example.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
```

and restart postfix with `sudo postfix reload`.

Comment: @nvidot thanks for the edit suggestion. You suggested a significant change from my answer. You should post it as a new answer. It sounds like a valid alternative answer to me, so in addition you should be able to get credit for it.

Answer (score 4):

The intended goal of the post owner is to know how to set the *Helo Address* in Postfix config and to know at what value it is *best* to set it. I'll make the hypothesis that by *best*, we should uderstand *the value that will give my mail the greatest chance to be accepted on delivery*.

The *helo line* is controlled by the [`smtp_helo_name`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_helo_name) parameter. It, by default, references the `myhostname` parameter.

```
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
```

In order to pass the [spf_helo test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#HELO_tests), you'll need to have a corresponding SPF record in your DNS for the address `smtp_helo_name` references.

If you already have configured such SPF record for your domain, a straigthforward way to achieve SPF helo check is to use the domain as helo name:

```
smtp_helo_name = $mydomain
```

But it is best practice to set it to the [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of the emitting host. This requires to have a SPF *for that* FQDN hostname in your DNS.

***Note:** The following holds for a single domain, just replace all occurrences of  *domainB* with *domainA*.* If *domainA* serves other domains, configure them similar to what is done for *domainB*.

For example suppose that the DNS for *domainB.tld* contains the following:

```
                       600 IN TXT    "v=spf1 mx -all"
                           IN MX     mx.domainA.tld
```

i.e. *domainA* hosts the SMTP server of *domainB*: `mx.domainA.tld`.

Then *domainA* DNS zone must contain a SPF record for host *mx*, along with the corresponding record that resolves to the IP address, for example:

```
mx                     600 IN TXT    "v=spf1 a -all"
mx                     600 IN A      A.B.C.D
```

then if `myhostname` references *mx.domainA.tld* you can let `smtp_helo_name` to its default value (i.e. `myhostname`) or you can configure it as needed.

Then [reload postfix configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/816139/restart-postfix-using-systemd-without-dropping-connections) (`systemctl reload postfix`).

[postfix](/questions/tagged/postfix)[smtp](/questions/tagged/smtp)[spf](/questions/tagged/spf)[ehlo](/questions/tagged/ehlo)[helo](/questions/tagged/helo)

Comment: Anecdotal, however, I have recently reviewed Spamhaus a blacklist provider and they stated that helo check should be ideally a [FQDN](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Hacked...%20Here's%20help#539). I wanted to leave that for others incase they are not sure and postfix manual says similar.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I initially configured this way because I was trying to achieve SPF helo check but was returned "SPF_helo: none: local="<fqdn_hostname>: No applicable sender policy available". Passing the domain as smtp_helo_name did work but indeed was not satisfactory, can't remember why exactly (may be something to do with GMAIL). So I eventually went back to default (i.e. $myhostname) as I realized that what was missing for it to pass helo check was a SPF record for the fqdn_hostname in addition to the SPF record for the domain itself.

Comment: And thank you for the follow-up. Now people don't have to spend hours hunting for information like this.